# Copy row from one worksheet and paste to another worksheet to next available row based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to check what have I done wrong in the code basically as in the title I would like to automatically copy from WS(ASN) and paste to another worksheet (Archive) into next available raw plus deleting the one (which I copied) from the first ws(Archive)

If in column "K" = "YES" then copy raw from column A-K paste to next available raw in worksheet (Archive) and delete raw in ws (ASN)

Please see the code and advise

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim MatchRow As Long, FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
     Dim Destination As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("ASN")

    FirstRow = 2
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

     Dim i As Long
    i = FirstRow
    Do While i <= LastRow
        If ws.Range("K" & i).Value = "YES" Then
            MatchRow = ws.Range("K" & i).Row

             With Sheets("Archive")
                Set Destination = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
             End With

 ws.Range("A" & MatchRow & ":K" & MatchRow).Copy Destination

 ws.Rows(MatchRow).EntireRow.Delete

LastRow = LastRow - 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, specify what part are you stuck. ¿Does your code fails at copying? ¿Does your code do not delete? Be more clear. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the issue by opening completely new macro.